# How do I convert time into an integer in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a date column and a time column that are integers

I converted the date portion like this

```
select convert(int, convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 112))
```

I thought I could do the same with this query that gives the time in HH:mm:ss

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108)
```

How do I convert just the time into an integer?

Comment: Do a datediff in seconds?

Comment: Do you mean seconds since midnight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for the "time" analogy to the "date" portion of your code which takes `YYYYMMDD` and turns it into an `INT`, you can:

1. start with the `HH:mm:ss` format given by the style number 108
2. remove the colons to get that string into `HHmmss`
3. then convert that to `INT`

For example:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108),
               ':',
               ''
              ) AS [StringVersion],

       CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(
                       CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108),
                       ':',
                       ''
                    )
              ) AS [IntVersion];
```

Answer (score 8):

This should convert your time into an integer representing seconds from midnight.

```
SELECT (DATEPART(hour, Col1) * 3600) + (DATEPART(minute, Col1) * 60) + DATEPART(second, Col1) as SecondsFromMidnight FROM T1;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the differece between midnight and the time of the day. For example, using getdate(), you can know the percentage of the time of the day with this query:

```
select convert(float,getdate()-convert(date,getdate()))
```

You can then convert this number to seconds

```
select convert(int,86400 * convert(float,getdate()-convert(date,getdate())))
```

You'll get the number of seconds from midnight

Answer (score -1):

I think this is easier to understand when using with a SQL Update statement.

UPDATE dbo.MyTable
SET TIME_AS_INT = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(CONVERT(Time(0), GETDATE()) AS varchar),':','') AS INT)

To add/subtract time from the result before converting use dateadd()

SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(CONVERT(Time(0), dateadd(MINUTE, 1, getdate())) AS varchar),':','') AS INT)